# What is the difference between @HostBinding() directive and ElementRef/Renderer?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I'm building a directive for a dropdown toggle. What I've seen is there are two approaches to build this directive. What should be the best practice?

### Approach 1 - Using @HostBinding()

```
@HostBinding('class.open') isOpen: boolean = false;   
@HostListener('click') toggleFunc(){   
   this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;   
}
```

### Approach 2 - Using ElementRef and Renderer

```
    isOpen: boolean = false;
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2){}

    @HostListener('click') onToggle(){
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
        if(this.isOpen){
            this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, "open");
        }
        else{
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, "open");    
        }

}
```

Approach 1 look better as it is just 3 lines of code (hassle-free). But what should be the best practice? What should I use while creating such directives?
Does `@HostBinding()` and `ElementRef/Renderer` have different use cases?

Comment: thanks for asking this question, I was trying to implement the seconde approach after seeing the first approach in a tutorial, but I couldn't. my mistake was writing ``this.renderer.setStyle``instead of ``this.renderer.addClass``.

Comment: This is from Maximilian Schwarzmüller angular course on udemy, I see you !

Answer (score 2):

Its better to use the @HostBinding() approach because the code looks much cleaner than Renderer2 approach.

But if you want to bypass Angular's templating and make custom UI changes you should use Renderer2 approach and create your own custom renderer. https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#description

Just don't directly manipulate the DOM.